# edit bash file using php script

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have been trying to run the bash script using php `shell_exec()`, before that i want to edit the bash variables using php script. 
Ex: i want to edit this *domainname, value, txtdata* values in the *editdns.sh* file before the execution.

**Bash script:**

```
#!bin/bash
domainname="mydomain.com"
value="mydomain.com."
txtdata="test2348734"
whmapi1 editzonerecord domain=$domainname line=24 name=$value class=IN ttl=14400 type=TXT txtdata=$txtdata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to edit your bash for that.
Do not use static values on variables. You can pass arguments to bash by command line.

```
#!bin/bash
domainname=$1
value=$2
txtdata=$3
whmapi1 editzonerecord domain=$domainname line=24 name=$value class=IN ttl=14400 type=TXT txtdata=$txtdata
```

better code:

```
#!bin/bash
whmapi1 editzonerecord domain=$1 line=24 name=$2 class=IN ttl=14400 type=TXT txtdata=$3
```

so you hav to run it using:

```
$myresults=shell_exec("editdns.sh mydomain.com mydomain.com. test2348734");
```

change to the correct path before excecute

```
$pathkeep = getcwd();  //keep the currect
chdir('/mypath/');    //change to the script path
$data = shell_exec('./editdns.sh var1 var2');    //excecute script
chdir($pathkeep );    //return to prev path
```

Comment: $data=shell_exec('/tmp/editdns.sh mydomain.com mydomain.com. test2348734'); print_r($data); It returns blank page

Comment: What you get, if you excecute the bash,  in command line manualy?

Comment: Yes, i executed in the command line manually. It was return the expected response and got update the records correctly. It doesn't return anything and not updated the TXT records when execute through the PHP file. file permission also set correctly

Comment: see the bottom of my answer

Comment: The issue is "whmapi1" command is only run as a sudo user. i tried this `sudo whmapi1 editzonerecord domain=$1 line=24 name=$2 class=IN ttl=14400 type=TXT txtdata=$3` it is working in the command line but not workiing in the bash file.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to change the shell script to accept command line arguments:

```
#!bin/bash
domainname=$1
value=$2
txtdata=$3
whmapi1 editzonerecord domain=$domainname line=24 name=$value class=IN ttl=14400 type=TXT txtdata=$txtdata
```

And then call the script from PHP with the required arguments:

```
$salida = shell_exec('/path/to/script.sh mydomain.com mydomain.com. test2348734');
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: `$data=shell_exec('/tmp/editdns.sh mydomain.com mydomain.com. test2348734');
print_r($data);` It returns blank page

Answer (score 1):

Don't change script, this may make some troubles or security problems. You may read parameters in bash script and in php call bash command with parameters:

```
#!bin/bash
domainname=$1 # <-- you can validate input here or in php
value=$2 # <-- you can validate input
txtdata=$3 # <-- you can validate input
whmapi1 editzonerecord domain=$domainname line=24 name=$value class=IN ttl=14400 type=TXT txtdata=$txtdata
```

a then in php command string:

```
editdns.sh "mydomain.com" "mydomain.com." "test2348734"
```